# Unchecked.defaultof on a list

Tags: f#

Consider:

```
> Unchecked.defaultof<list<int>>;;
val it : int list = null
> 2 :: 1 :: Unchecked.defaultof<list<int>>;;
val it : int list = [2]
```

What's the reasoning behind this behavior? I would expect the final list to be [2;1] or raise an exception.

Comment: That is strange. How do you even stumble upon something like this? ;)

Comment: It seemed natural to use Array.zeroCreate to initialize an array of lists. I knew it would use Unchecked.defaultof but I thought the worst that would happen would be an exception. But apparently I was horribly wrong.

Comment: This is probably because F# assumes many things are not null - note that `Unchecked.defaultof<list<int>><>[]`.  I guess the first cons call somehow thros stuff away - also `1::null` throws an exception.  I t is possible that `defaultof` should return `[]` instead of `null`

Comment: But wait - it gets weirder - `> match 1::Unchecked.defaultof<_> with
- |1::_ -> printfn "has one"             
- |_ -> printfn "wtf";;               
has one 
` and `1::Unchecked.defaultof<_> |> List.length ;;val it : int = 0
`

Comment: That must be an optimization if you match |1::x then x is null meanwhile if you assign "let a = 1::Unchecked.defaultof<_>" and match a you'll get "wtf"

Comment: I think this should be emailed to the F# bugs email - fsbugs@microsoft.com

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is pretty amazing question. I looked how F# lists are compiled and it explains the behaviour. I would not consider this as bug (that's why `defaultof` is in the `Unchecked` module, it might as well burn down your computer!)

First of all, the empty list `[]` is not represented as `null` in F# 2.0, because then you would not be able to invoke methods on empty list - and this would break many things (like passing empty list to any `Seq` function). As an aside, the `None` value *is* represented as `null` for efficiency, which means that `option<'a>` cannot implement the `seq<'a>` interface even though it would make sense.

So instead, F# uses a special value `list.Empty` to represent empty lists. Now this value is an instance of the same type as values representing non-empty list (the type is `FSharpList<'T>`). The only difference is that both `head` and `tail` fields of the instance are `null`.

Now, you can maybe see where this is going - an empty list is essentially compiled to an object where the `this.tail` field is `null` (and the `this.head` field is `null` too, but this is not that important).

The `list.Tail` property will throw an exception when the field `this.tail` is `null` (because this means you're getting the tail of an empty list - which is an error), but there is also an internal property `list.TailOrNull` which returns the value without checking and which is used to compile pattern matching.

For example, here is a simple `iter` function:

```
let rec iter (xs:int list) = 
  match list with
  | x::xs -> Console.WriteLine(x); iter xs
  | [] -> ()
```

This is compiled to the following C# code:

```
if (list.TailOrNull != null) {
  Console.WriteLine(list.HeadOrDefault);
  iter(list.TailOrNull);
}
```

This checks whether `list` is an empty list by checking whether its `list.TailOrNull` is `null`. If it is then it knows that the current `list` value is the `list.Empty` value representing an empty list (and it does not print its `HeadOrDefault` because it assumes that this is `null` too).

If you use `defaultof` to create `null` value explicitly then `42::null` gives you an object where `TailOrNull` is `null` but `HeadOrDefault` is `42`. So that's why the value is not printed.

**TL;DR** - Do not use `Unchecked.defaultof` with F# types. You never know what will happen.

Comment: But what about all the zero create functions?